# How to prints object of object in JavaScript after success ajax call?

Tags: json, javacv

`[["QQQ", "ABC"], ["XYZ", "ABD"], ["RTY", "XXX"], ["PPP", "UUU"]]`

Need to print after success [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) call in tabular form i.e.

example: `["QQQ", "ABC"] ["XYZ", "ABD"]`,

```
  Part1    Part2
   QQQ     ABC
   XYZ     ABD
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but if you want to print string array

`var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.toString();`